# Java: is there any way to add property in JsonObject at specific position?

Tags: json, gson

The method addProperty of JsonObject can add property in the last place of json. But can I specify the position where i insert property?

Answer (score 0):

Properties of objects in JSON are not guaranteed to have a defined order. Your Java library is adding it always at the end because of how it's internally implemented, but that could change from one version to the next.  If you want to keep the order of things in a JSON you need to use arrays.